# My Goole Home Action unlock the lock successfully, but test suite failed, what's wrong?

Tags: google-home

My action used to work fine, this problem started from about two months ago, the users complaiming the lock is unlocked successfully, but Google Assist reponse him with not responding.
Then I try run the test suite, the test suite failed too for a long time( about 30s) with error message: *AssertionError: Expected state to include: {"isLocked":false}, actual state: {"isLocked":true,"isJammed":false,"online":true}: expected false to be true*
But I've responed in the fullfillment in about 4s with right results like following:
*{"payload":{"agentUserId":11424,"commands":[{"ids":["2240971"],"status":"SUCCESS","states":{"isLocked":false,"isJammed":false,"online":true}}]},"requestId":"9734864624346816785"}*

I just don't know what's wrong, please help.

Answer (score -1):

Issue seems to be from report state not being delivered in time, or correctly. Make sure to report state within a few seconds after execution and get a HTTP 200 OK response. You can also verify whether the states in homegraph are actually changing through [Home Graph Viewer](https://smarthome-test-suite.withgoogle.com/devices)